# Unable to Open TV app

Tags: ios, tv.app

I have iOS 10.2 on my iPhone. I can't access TV app. It is not getting opened at all. It struck for 2-3 minutes and even after that it is not getting opened.

Do anybody have idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Tv App is only available in US Store, if you are residing out side of US, and trying to open the tv app it will not open.

For example: I'm resident of india and i used US APP Store to download TV App. After downloading i tried to open it, but no luck. Then i switched back to indian store and Videos app appeared instead of TV app.